# Is it memory safe piece of code?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

```
NSMutableArray *m_res = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:ticks];
double t = lo_t;
while (t <= hi_t) {
    [m_res addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:
                      [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:t] decimalValue]
                      ]];
    t += delta_t;
}

return [[NSArray arrayWithArray:m_res] retain];
```

It is supposed to return a persistent NSArray containing some values. I plan to call release on it when it is no longer needed. Is it ok or there's some bug, because when I call function containing this code my program stops working (and it's a memory issue not endless loop).

Comment: Can you give us a stack trace, or tell us what error you get and on what line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is *safe* (ie won't crash) but the last line is incorrect.
The **arrayWithArray** is doing nothing useful and the retain is a leak.

It should be

```
return m_res;
```

If you hava a crash the cause is elsewhere.

Comment: Again, an array returned from `arrayWithCapacity` will already be autoreleased, you don't need to autorelease it. You also shouldn't `retain` the array in this method, as it is the caller's responsibility to retain/release as nescessary; doing it in this method could lead to leaks later on as the caller may not realise they need to `release` the instance. The exception would be if this was an `init` method, which this doesn't appear to be.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, the retain/autorelease is unnecessary, i have removed it, but it wasn't a leak and the caller wouldnt need to release it.

Comment: You have fixed it, but the original **would** leak. With your unnescessary retain/autorelease, the array would have a retain count of 3 (the inital autorelease, your retain, and your autorelease on exit would each increment the retain count). When the autorelease pool was emptied, it would be autoreleased twice, but that would only bring the retain count down to 1, so it would be a leak (unless the caller new he had to release it, in which case this would be bad design, the object that retains is responible for releasing, and vice versa).

Comment: @toiletseat No, this is incorrect. Please refer to the memory management guidelines http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Comment: @mustISignUP, which part specifically do you disagree with? The key point, from the article you link to, is **You only release or autorelease objects you own**. The corollary is also true - you should only retain objects you are going to release. As this is a public method that anyone can call, this is not nescessarily true. It is the caller's responsibility to retain if he wants to, as it is he who would be doing the releasing later.

Comment: @toiletseat - you don't seem to understand what autorelease does

Comment: @mustISignUp, I do understand. Sending `autorelease` increments the retain count, and adds the receiver to the autorelease pool. When the autorelease pool empties at some later point (typically at the end of the run loop), then each object in the pool will get sent a release message. Your original code called autorelease twice, incrementing the retain count twice, in addition to the `retain` message incrementing it. When the run loop finished, the autorelease pool would empty, calling `release` on your object twice. So, you are left with a retain count of one, and a leak (or a bad design).

Comment: @toiletseat - No, that isn't what it does.

Comment: @toiletseat - it's best to get it from Apple's docs, but -autorelease does not increment the retain count. It is only a deferred decrement.

Comment: @mustISignUp, my mistake, I thought it also incremented the retain count.